# Usage software documentation as a valid reference?

Tags: citations

I'm in the process of writing my paper and have found a very helpful answer from a luminary in this field on [Stackoverflow](https://www.stackoverflow.com). Logically, the answer cannot be taken as a valid source. However, I found the graphic that was attached in the answer in the documentation of a [Linear Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) [solver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Solvers_and_scripting_(programming)_languages) that was developed by this person, among others. Is documentation a valid source that is also accepted in specialist journals or not?

Comment: Plenty of journal articles reference specific software or specific algorithms.

Comment: But it refers to an "insight" not to the software itself

Answer (score 7):

References are used to explain where you have information from, or where others might find the information refer to. It is, in this light, not terribly important whether the source you reference is a journal article, a book, or someone's blog. It is certainly *useful* if these sources are available long-term (as is the case with journals and books), and it is useful to cite sources that are vetted (for example via peer review), but it is not necessary. As a consequence, software manuals, blog posts, answers on StackExchange, etc., are all valid sources you should reference if you use the information there.

Comment: At an extreme, if you learn something while talking to a colleague during your coffee break at the coffee machine, you can use it and reference it as "private communication with XYZ".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, software documentation can and should be cited. If you can find a journal paper that contains the same information, cite that too.

It is best to find and cite the most solid source you can find, e.g. a journal paper or book. These are likely to be reliably available to readers and they are generally more trustworthy than webpages.

But if you found the information on StackExchange then you can cite that too. To make a webpage permanently available you can tag it to be stored by https://archive.org/web/ (see other answers on this site).

Answer (score 0):

From a purely scholarly point of view, citing the documentation for the software you use is an excellent thing to do. It enables the reader to learn where it was that you obtained your information and to verify the source if they wish to. The fact that you might be referring to an "insight" or general concept that is mentioned or explained in the documentation ***doesn't change the fact*** that the documentation is the source of your knowledge. There are some fascinating insights about typography, for example, in Donald Knuth's books (i.e., the documentation!) on [TeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX) and [Metafont](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metafont). It would seem truly bizarre to reject those as appropriate sources of insights on typography simply because that happen also to be the documentation for software.

On a different note, if the software that you are using happens to be open-source and developed by volunteers, or developed with the assistance of grant money, then an additional reason to cite the software documentation is to draw attention to the usefulness of the software and (indirectly) increase the likelihood of additional funding becoming available.

The first place that I came across a specific [request for citation](http://psychtoolbox.org/credits) was on the site for [Psychtoolbox](http://psychtoolbox.org/). Since then, I've found that it seems to be almost universal on grant-supported packages and applications such as [ESPResSo](https://espressomd.org/wordpress/about/please-cite-us/), [KIR*IMP](https://imp.science.unimelb.edu.au/kir/publications), and [GNU R](https://ropensci.org/blog/2021/11/16/how-to-cite-r-and-r-packages/) . If you search with your favorite search-engine using `software "please cite us" OR "please cite as"`, you will find many more.